# Http GetJsonAsync returns null from server API

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am trying to create an application using Blazor and .NET Core 3 with EF Core 3. I have setup a database model and an API for users (/api/users) and browsing to this in chrome returns all of the entities in the database. My GetJson method in the Razor file returns null however.

Here is my Razor code file:

```html
@page "/"
@using LogicX.Shared
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>Users</h1>

@functions{
    User[] _users;
    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        var users = await Http.GetJsonAsync<User[]>("/api/users");
        _users = users;
    }
}
@foreach (var usr in _users)
{
    <td>@usr.Username</td>
}
```

The GetJsonAsync method seems to return null, in spite of records being in the database and in spite of the fact i am able to view the entities in Json format by browsing to /api/users. Is my implementation of this correct and does anyone know how to potentially fix this issue?

Edit: Server Side Code:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly LogicXDbContext _context;

    public UsersController(LogicXDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Users
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
    {
        return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Users/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUser(int id)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return user;
    }

    // PUT: api/Users/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutUser(int id, User user)
    {
        if (id != user.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!UserExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Users
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
    {
        _context.Users.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Users/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> DeleteUser(int id)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Users.Remove(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return user;
    }

    private bool UserExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Users.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also please edit the question with server-side code as well

Comment: @GerritBergen Edited post. No errors in console. The request completes with a successful HTTP 200 code.

Comment: Ok, just to rule some things out. Use the url "api/Users/GetUsers" in your client. Also set the Return type on the API to "Task<ActionResult<List<User>>>".
Please also change the recieving type to the List<User> instead of User[]

Let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: Hey another thing I noticed, you have a forward slash in the beginning of your query url. Make sure that isn't there. There's a bug right now where adding that will result in failure.

Comment: @Adam Creed, do you have Fiddler or Postman ? If you do, please run it and query your Web API for the GetUsers method ? Do you see data retrieved ?

Comment: @GerritBergen Sorry for not updating you, currently on holiday coding so internet isn't the most reliable. I've tried your suggestion and GetUsers isn't a recognised type. I also tried changing the receiving type which also did not work. I also removed the / from the api url at the beginning which did not work. Going to try and download Fiddler but like I said internet isn't the most reliable :) Thanks for all of the suggestions! If anyone has anything else to add it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @GerritBergen So here's an idea. Whenever I reference the model directly on the client, it throws a weird compiler error. Something about EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions couldn't be found. To resolve this, i removed the reference to the model from the client project and added a duplicate class for the User in the shared project. Could this potentially be the cause for the issue? Both classes are identical, so I don't think it should matter. I can make my GitHub code public if anyone wishes to dig deeper into my code.

Comment: Yes, post a reference to the complete app...

Comment: Usually when I pass data from server to client I use a ViewModel, which doesn't have any references to the Database/EntityFramework so I'm not sure. Github source would be great. My github username is GerritBergen if you'd rather keep it private. Although I probably can't take a look until later.

Comment: @GerritBergen Ok, I feel really stupid right now. It works. Turns out your list suggestion solved it, but I had multiple tabs open with the app in and I was looking at one of those instead of the correct one. Thanks for the help! Could you please answer the question so I can mark it as resolved? Cheers.

Comment: @Issac Also, it doesn't work with the / in front, as you suggested.

Comment: @AdamCreed Glad to hear it works! Hey we've all been there. Figuring some of these little things out took me quite some time too. (especially that "/", man that was a pain XD) I've added my answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a forward slash in front of the url is bugged right now, so no requests will go through.
Use `api/Users/GetUsers` in your client instead.

Set the Return type on the API to `Task<ActionResult<List<User>>>` and change the receiving type to `List<User>` instead of `User[]`.

Doing this will ensure that the sending and receiving types don't mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Make sure that the class you're trying to send is a property with getters and setters:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue in a later version. However in my instance it appears it was objecting to the object being created with a constructor. Removing the constructor and creating the object as below worked.

var personal = new Personal() {YearofBirth = 1966, Gender="M", Email= "alex@test.com"};